# Can I log the script that invokes DELETE query?

Tags: postgresql

I have to investigate who or what caused tables rows to disappear.
So, I am thinking about creating "on before delete" trigger that logs the script that invokes the deletion. Is this possible? Can I get the db client name or event better - the script that invokes delete query and log it to another temporarly created log table?
I am open to other solutions, too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get "the script" which issued the `delete` statement, but you can get various other information:

- `current_user` will return the current Postgres user that initiated the `delete` statement
- `inet_client_addr()` will return the IP address of the client's computer
- `current_query()` will return the complete statement that caused the trigger to fire

More details about that kind of of functions are available in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html

The Postgres Wiki contains two examples of such an audit trigger:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger (somewhat outdated)